# css selecting n elemtns every

Tags: html, css

What I'm trying to achieve here is to have first 6 rows without changing background, then next 6 rows change background to gray and so on...

Below example how I'm approaching this, but obviously doesn't work properly, number of elements is wrong, what do I do wrong? Can it be done easier, cleaner?

```
table tr:nth-child(13n-1), 
table tr:nth-child(13n-2),
table tr:nth-child(13n-3), 
table tr:nth-child(13n-4), 
table tr:nth-child(13n-5),
table tr:nth-child(13n-6) {
    background: gray;
}
```

[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maximhash/cj3rw19w/)

Comment: You need to use 12 as multiplier and have `12n` as one child instead of `13n-6`. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/cj3rw19w/1/) is the sample.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed!